# Python: Print exact item, find array element in array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can I print the item that is found? (without for-loop?) I want to find elements of array 1 in array 2 and then print those elements.

```
check = any(item in p for item in words)
print(check) # Result is TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use set intersection:

```
x = ['1', '2', '3']
y = ['2', '3', '4']

print(set(x).intersection(y))


output: {'2', '3'}
```

You can find more info on intersection [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp), note a set cannot contain any duplicates. I wasn't sure if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
empty_lst = [print(item) for item in words if item in p]
```

`empty_lst` will store `[]`
To store the cross-over items, do;

```
cross_items = [item for item in words if item in p]
```

The reason your question doesnt work is that `item in p` will always return a boolean value so `item in p if item in words` returns a list of `True` and `False`.
`if item in p` checks for the item. Look up tutorials in list comprehension to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think yo can do that.
any returns a Boolean value

```
word = ["your list"]
numbers = ["numbers you want to check for"]
for i in word:
    if i in numbers:
        print(i)
```